# Is it possible to have a GraphQL mutation that contains various input values for a specific key?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

From my client I'm trying to send something with the following structure to my server...

```js
{
  pet: cat,
  food: [
    {
      brand: "Meow Mix",
      types: "dry"
    },
    {
      brand: "Friskies",
      types: {
         type1: dry,
         type2: wet,
      }, 
    },
    
  ]
}
```

You can see that `types` can either be a `string` or `object`. Presume more brands will be added to the array that will contain either a `string` or `object` for `types`. Is it even possible to send this sort of structure via GraphQL? If so, how would the type be structured? Ideally it would be great to use a `union` here but that's not available for mutatations.

```
input Pets {
  pet: String!,
  food: [Brands!]!
}

input Brands {
  brand: String!,
  types: String! | FoodOptions  // here is where I'm getting stuck. i know `or` isn't possible but don't know of a different solution.
}

input FoodOptions {
  type1: String!,
  type2: String
}
```

Comment: why objects? unify that - use array with one or two elements, throw error (don't accept input) if more?

Comment: I'm using objects because it works best based on the data that I'm manipulating.

Comment: 'it works best' looks like a bit easier [only in some places and hardcoded!] for me - changing string or object into input array (mutation variable) is an easy task - reading/consuming data from array is easier, too